# Stack Overflow Jobs not exporting all accounts

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When viewed from the web link the all the accounts show up the way that they are supposed to (I assume the way they are supposed to), but when I try to export/create a pdf only Stack Overflow shows up in my projects and interests.

While Stack Overflow is one of the accounts that I actually want to share, I actually have more reputation on Code Review and want that listed.

Online version

[image: Online Version]

Export to PDF Version

[image: Export To PDF Version]

and the Mark Down Version

[image: Mark Down Version]

Is this the intended result?

I was hoping that I could share my Code Review Profile through this media as well.